# How to find number of duplicate companies in database, of same or similar name

Tags: sql, select, group-by

So far, I'm doing:

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(*)
FROM companies c
group by c.name
HAVING COUNT(*) >1;
```

but obviously this doesn't permit me to find companies with similar but not exactly the same name. How do I find this?

For instance, same name is:

```
Walmart Inc.

Walmart Inc.
```

Different names are:

```
Walmart Inc.

Walmart, Inc

Walmart

Walmart Incorporated etc.
```

These companies should be identified as the same despite their name difference.

Comment: Please define precisely *similar but not exactly the same*. Sample data and desired results would help clarifying your problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often called a fuzzy search, and is a concept most often found in relation to full text searching.  The problem for you is that you've added grouping to the problem.

So for your specific example you're going to need to create an intermediate table that contains all forms of the text to map back to a single groupable entity (foreign key).

If you just wanted to search for all forms of Walmart you could use `like '%Walmart%'` or a `where contains(name, "Walmart")` etc *depending on your flavor of SQL*.  But those are simple search where clauses.  You are trying to group by all known variations which means you have to first identify all known variations within your table and then map to a single **deterministic** mapping key or value.

Doing a quick google search [gives this walkthrough](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/sqlquerychat/sql-help/data-query/sql-fuzzy-logic-matching-step-by-step-example-in-sql-server/) as an example.

If you ONLY cared about Walmart you could probably get away with a complex CTE that drops all forms of Walmart into a single key on the fly... but I'm guessing there are a lot more items in your table than just one that have various forms.

Moral of the story... this is the result of poor data quality/data management up front that you end up having to pay for later with this type of work.

Comment: yea I'm trying this for all companies in the database. Seems like it might be tough. Thanks!

Comment: most of us find ourselves there at some point... good luck